# Смещается код на git hub

Tags: github

Вот тут, например смещаются первые строки: https://github.com/olijen/travel/blob/master/protected/migrations/m120328_085408_base_db.php
Как этого избежать?

Comment: Что и куда у вас там смещается?

Answer (score 6):

Я так полагаю, вас не устраивают размеры отступов при отображении кода. У вас есть целых 3 варианта решения этой проблемы:

1. Используйте пробелы вместо табов для отступа
2. Добавляйте в конец URL параметр `ts=4`. Это заставит Github заменять при отображении табы на указанное число пробелов. Пример: https://github.com/olijen/travel/blob/master/protected/migrations/m120328_085408_base_db.php?ts=4
3. Добавьте пользовательский стиль для Github при помощи расширения Stylish, в котором измените размер табуляции.

Готовый стиль можно взять [здесь](https://userstyles.org/styles/70979/github-better-sized-tabs-in-code) или использовать этот код:

```
.tab-size {
  -webkit-tab-size: 4 !important;
     -moz-tab-size: 4 !important;
       -o-tab-size: 4 !important;
          tab-size: 4 !important;
}
```

Comment: 1) У меня IDE переводит табы в пробелы. 2) Это точно не выход=) 3) Попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Перепроверьте настройки вашей IDE. Если загрузить файл в чистом виде (кнопка Raw на Github), можно убедиться, что отступы сделаны табами.